# RDL reports shows images flipped (rotated 180 degrees) when exported to PDF

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdl

So in the regular report viewer the images show correctly oriented.  When the report is exported to PDF or WORD document, the pictures (some, not all) appear rotated...

Comment: I've tried changing the image property from fit proportional to fit to size, clip... nothing seems to affect that behavior

Comment: I've not come across this issue myself. How are the images referenced, are they embedded in the report, external images or taken from a database image column? If a database image, what database are you using? Could you share links to a couple of the images, one that works and one that does not.

Comment: I would check to see if it's an issue with the image type. Open a known affected pic in Paint, save as BMP, try using BMP file in report to see if it comes out better.

Comment: Images are JPG, they are external.  480x720.  I heard about issues with png's and large format.  But, this isn't the case.

Comment: Can you share 1 working and 1 non-working image so we can download and test?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the pics.  However I found that in the exif information the picture orientation was "Rotate 180 CW".  Having said that, is there a way to overcome this in SSRS?  SSRS seems to be displaying the picture in its original state.

Comment: There's no setting for the image in SSRS. I think the only way to be consistent is to convert the images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771795/how-to-fix-exif-orientation-data-in-jpg-files

Comment: If possible, you could batch convert all the images to correct their rotation. There are a few tools listed in this thread, which covers the same process https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11098.0 GIMP might have a plugin too, I've not checked but the idea is to read each image, rotate it based on the EXIF info, then save it rotated and remove the rotation in the EXIF metadata. Good luck!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the exact same thing happen. My pictures were all taken portrait, show up correctly in report viewer, but then when exported or printed, some of the pictures show up landscape in the resulting PDF, TIFF, etc (I've tried them all).